# sed stops working inside bash script but works in the shell

Tags: bash, sed

Been having some issues with variables and sed.
XMLStarlet removes the newlines from the XML which are required for openssl to read and replaces them with spaces

When executing

```sh
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//DecryptionKey' "file.xml" | sed $"s/ /\\\r\\n/g"
```

the key gets formatted properly with \r\n instead of spaces

however running the exact same piece of code in the bash script nothing gets changed, same exact space containing string

```sh
XML_DecryptionKey=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//DecryptionKey' "$1" | sed $"s/ /\\\r\\n/g")
```

I have no clue what to do, I tried it with perl, tr, awk but it just wont replace in the script.

Edit:

XML File

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<KDM>
<Metadata>
<ProjectName>U2FsdGVkX19cW2e8E2ZrzV3q18NGPmGJWCWTttOd+S4=</ProjectName>
<Encrypted>true</Encrypted>
<CustomerID>U2FsdGVkX1/SF8OjyGWfCxB3DMm6PxR/L4o6YhvcHBM=</CustomerID>
<Expires>U2FsdGVkX19HzhPXAC8tnr6P5C8Rl+4TKhMdviwrQ77v0GVhrmXDE95dq2A9PUQc
uIraONz1A4CVzlp7BbECmw==</Expires>
</Metadata>
<DecryptionKey>U2FsdGVkX19V/n561XAGZWpPSRsQ80iAtw5liYzYMfhkJ6m2XfMaOj59AmP4+H1x
4Y6n3I2WrfNEjDqoNsqkapoi+DCMDQQhwfVkj3LiuFUOIi+dzqz84xnNDzobsMb0
...
znVSKgDdLFd0EE8d3u83IlkLd+AloxfjZBjxcaLg9qOdWXFYWBr1S5/mObAJiGoO
x1K1W19T9TR48rDOLZ7zgw==</DecryptionKey>
</KDM>
```

Image:

[image: XML]

[image: XMLstarlet]

Comment: What is the command you're using to run the script?

Comment: ./xmldecrypt.sh file.xml

Comment: Do you have a shebang in the file? What is it?

Comment: The shebang is `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Here's what I did: 1. Create a `file.xml` containing `<Body> <DecryptionKey>Foo Bar</DecryptionKey> <DecryptionKey>Baz</DecryptionKey> </Body>`. 2. Run your shell command, the output is three lines `Foo\r`, `Bar`, `Baz` without trailing linefeed. 3. Put your script command in a file `xmldecrypt.sh` with `#!/bin/bash` before it and `printf '%s' "$XML_DecryptionKey"` after. 4. `chmod +x xmldecrypt.sh`. 5. Run `./xmldecrypt.sh file.xml`. The output is again three lines with `Foo\r`, `Bar`, `Baz` without trailing linefeed, exactly as before. How do I reproduce this?

Comment: Just posted the XML file (cropped decryption key) to the original file, it also seems that xmlstarlet converts the new line to a space and I dont know how to prevent it (see image)

Comment: Are you seeing this from your original command? You're not doing `echo $XML_DecryptionKey` right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205893/discussion-between-selectjb-and-that-other-guy).